# How to trigger github CI once PR get merged

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

I want to trigger my GitHub **ci** after merge request get merged. because i want to ship my source from **GitHub** to **gitlab** after merge request merged in **GitHub**

> Example
>   - https://github.com/kumaresan-subramani/ej2-blaz-doc/pull/7

CI getting triggered once pull request getting created, but after merge it won't trigger CI so that I am not able to ship my source from github to gitlab

[image]

My yml file :

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
    types: [opened, closed]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: set environment variables
      uses: allenevans/set-env@v1.0.0
      with:
          MY_ENV_VAR: 'my value'
          GIT_USER: ${{ secrets.USER }}
          GIT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
    - name: Install
      run: npm i
    - name: Publish
      run: npm run publish
      if: github.event.pull_request.merged == 'true'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to compare the field value `merged` with boolean value, not string.

```
github.event.pull_request.merged == true
```

instead of `github.event.pull_request.merged == 'true'`

You could also write:

```
if: github.event.pull_request.merged
```

For instance the following workflow compare the values when you open/close a PR :

```
on: 
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, closed]
name: build
jobs:
  build:
    name: Input check
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checking your input
        run: |
          echo "github.event.pull_request.merged           : $MERGED_RAW"
          echo "github.event.pull_request.merged == 'true' : $MERGED_TRUE_STR"
          echo "github.event.pull_request.merged  == true  : $MERGED_TRUE_BOOL"
        env:
          MERGED_RAW: ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged }}
          MERGED_TRUE_STR: ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged == 'true' }}
          MERGED_TRUE_BOOL: ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged == true }}
```

When you merged the PR, you've got the following result :

```
github.event.pull_request.merged           : true
github.event.pull_request.merged == 'true' : false
github.event.pull_request.merged == true   : true
```

Comment: This helped me a lot solving a more complex trigger situation that needed to care about PR and merging as well as some other things. It was assumed that the "true" would work too which was quickly discovered to not be the case.

Comment: @Bertrand
When we have multiple Jobs then
how to run deploy only on merge(push)



jobs:
     test-and-build: // run on pull and merge(push) both this is working fine.
         // build code
     deploy: // I want to run deploy only on merge(push)
         require: test-and-build
         // deploy code

Comment: At the time of writing (Dec 2022), it did not work for me without specifying `types: [closed]`. Looking at the documentation, it also says: "By default, a workflow only runs when a pull_request event's activity type is opened, synchronize, or reopened."

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request

Comment: @Beolap that's stated in their documentation, so I consider it the expected behavior https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-workflow-when-a-pull-request-merges

Comment: @javierlga, yep didn't read the docs previously and expected the default behaviour to be all types.